Why doesn't Lagrangian multiplier give any useful message for matrix optimization problem?
Let $\mathcal{H}^n$ be the space of dimension-$n$ Hermitian matrix space. Given $A\in\mathcal{H}^n$, consider the following optimization problem:
\begin{align*}
    &\max f(X,Y)=\text{tr}(XAYA)-\left(\text{tr}(X)\right)^2\\
    \text{s.t  }& X,Y\in\mathcal{H}^n\\
    &-I\preceq X \preceq I, -I\preceq Y \preceq I
\end{align*}
Here $A\preceq B$ means $B-A$ is positive semidefinite. My question is how to use the Lagrangian of the problem to get the conditions for optimal $X,Y$?
Denote $M=\{(X,Y):X,Y\in\mathcal{H}^n,-I\preceq X \preceq I, -I\preceq Y \preceq I\}$
If $X,Y$ are interior point of $M$, that is $-I\prec X \prec I, -I\prec Y \prec I$, for optimal $X,Y$ $\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial Y}=0$, that is $AYA=(2\text{tr}(X))I,AXA = 0$.
The problem here is to deal with the case $(X,Y)$ is on the boundary of $M$, where we need to get the Lagrangian of a matrix function. deal with the case $(X,Y)$ is on the boundary of $M$, where we need to get the Lagrangian of a matrix function.
Suppose Lagrangian $L(X,Y,\Lambda_1,...,\Lambda_4)=f(X,Y)+\text{tr}(\Lambda_1(-I-X)+\Lambda_2(X-I)+\Lambda_3(-I-Y)+\Lambda_4(Y-I))$,from KKT conditions we have:
$\Lambda_1,...\Lambda_4\succeq 0$
$\frac{\partial L}{\partial X}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial Y}=0$, that is $AYA-2tr(X)I-\Lambda_1+\Lambda_2=0,AXA-\Lambda_3+\Lambda_4=0$.
$Tr(\Lambda_1(-I-X))=Tr(\Lambda_2(X-I))=Tr(\Lambda_3(-I-Y))=Tr(\Lambda_4(Y-I))=0$
Here we can't eliminate $\Lambda_1,...\Lambda_4$, so using Lagrangian multiplier doesn't give any useful message. Why is the case? And how to analyze the optimal conditions of this problem?

First order optimality conditions are (12)-(14) of https://support.nag.com/numeric/cl/nagdoc_cl26/html/e04/e04svc.html , with all epsilons equal to zero.
